# Cake email not working

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Cake email not working

here is the code
app/config/email.php

```
public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'abcd@gmail.com',
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

and in app/controller/UsersController

```
email = new CakeEmail();
                $email->template('activate_your_account', 'default')
                        ->config('smtp')
                        ->emailFormat('html')
                        ->subject(__('Account Verification - ' . Configure::read('Application.name')))
                        ->to($user)
                        ->from(Configure::read('Application.from_email'))
                        ->viewVars(array('hash' => $hash, 'id' => $id))
                        ->send();
```

When I run this I get error like `An internal error has occurred`. please help me with it.

Edit : Now I have resolved this error thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure an SMTP server. See this page for details: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Your example shows no mail server config